# how get a bit "bolder" or "blurry" and more weight font on arch linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig

this could be a weird question because many people seems to ask for the opposite question: How get more defined fonts on linux?..

unfortunately I came from OS and notice than the linux font looks so skinny and need more weight and for me (maybe is than I'm used to a bit bolder font) it's becoming a nightmare programming on linux with that font

in the past I use infinality with decent results, unfortunately seems than this package is becoming obsolete and (at least on arch) can't be installed in a simple way...

are there some way for get and change the font look on linux?..right now I'm using manjaro KDE, I've changed all the settings on the system preference/font type/use border hitting with no look

hope you can help me, thank so much!!!